# How to read XML attribute from a TABLE?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

The database have Table EMP with 3 columns empID , badgID , XMLDATA.

The XMLDATA have datatype "clob" and data is in the form -

```
<Record id="11">
    <Demo rID="5"/>
</Record>
```

How can I read the attribute "rID" in node "Demo"value in the above XMLDATA in single query?

Server - SQL Server 2005

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What is the actual datatype? `clob` isn't a SQL Server datatype as far as I know.

Comment: Seriously - datatype "CLOB" ?? As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't have that - we have `IMAGE, TEXT, NTEXT` (all obsolete) or then `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` or `XML` - so which is it really??

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data stored with datatype XML in SQL Server, then you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    empID, badgID,
    XmlData.value('(/Record/Demo/@rID)[1]', 'int') as 'rID'
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
```

If your datatype is **not** XML - it really should be! You might need to use something like this (might not work in all cases):

```
SELECT 
    empID, badgID,
    (CAST XmlData AS XML).value('(/Record/Demo/@rID)[1]', 'int') as 'rID'
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks.
I tried both queries ,it fails and says "schema XMLDATA does not exist."
But XMLDATA column is present in the Table.

Comment: @indigenious: can you show us the actual table structure, e.g. a database diagram or something??

Comment: My apologies , i only have read access to the database and do not aware about the architecture.